# How to get a Java import to use the most recent version?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm having a problem with the import for Jackson, an XML/Json parser, being an old version. There's a specific bug(empty object is not properly parsed) that's preventing me from outputting what I need. This was fixed in version 2.3.1, but apparently the import my project is using is version 2.2.2

How can I tell Java or Eclipse to fetch the most recent version?

I would expect that simply doing an import, for instance:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
```

Would fetch the latest version. But ti doesn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to download the latest version of the `.jar` file and place it in your project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the current jar from the latest version of the jar. This is the site to download the jars: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/

If you use maven, just replace the version in the dependency it in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```